# Finding the monthly open and closing values from a list of daily stock/index data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of daily stock/index data with columns for open, high, low and close. The data is for one year and goes from row 3 to row 254. I am trying to extract the monthly opening value (and closing value) for each month but I can't manage to do this as the first day of the month is different for most months. I have the array formula for the high value for each month (shown in the picture) and low value which works fine and wondered whether anybody could help with a similar formula to extract the opening data (and closing data) for each month. For the month of January the opening value would be 3764.61 and for February 3731.17. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly share markdown sample data. Too much work to start typing this to help you out =). Also, please include your own attempt you have in the formula-bar now.

Comment: Try `minifs`?..

Comment: I've tried that but the min condition would be on the day in the monthly date, not the data?

Comment: Any chance you could help me on the formatting for the MINIFS command? I can't seem to specify the criteria correctly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ranges do not change and using the same function you are already using to determine High and Low, you can add the following functions in cells M3 and P3 respectively for the Open and Close columns and then filter down.

```
=MIN(IF((MONTH($C$3:$C$254)=K3)*(YEAR($C$3:$C$254)=J3),$D$3:$D$254))
=MAX(IF((MONTH($C$3:$C$254)=K3)*(YEAR($C$3:$C$254)=J3),$G$3:$G$254))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it doesn't work; I've come up with similar formulae. For the January open number your code returns 3698.02, which is the lowest opening value in January, but not the desired number which is 3764.61. the first value in the month (4th January open value). The opening value for each month is tied to the lowest date in that month which is not always the 1st day of the month, hence the difficulty.

Comment: On my end it is returning 3764.61 for open for January 2021 and for close it is returning 3714.24. I would review the ranges to make sure they are starting on C3.

Comment: In the spreadsheet J3=2021, the year but you have it associated with the month? And I3 on the spreadsheet is blank but you have it associated with the month. I'm assuming that in your formula you mean K3 for the month not J3 and J3 for the year not I3? On that basis I don't get your numbers? I'm assuming that it is an array?

Comment: Thanks for everybody's help so far but unfortunately my question remains unanswered. Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: I edited my answer. I assumed you changed the range in your spreadsheet. Did it do what you expected?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What your code does is check that the month and year are correct and on the basis of that chooses the minimum value in that month from the open column and the maximum value from the closing column. What is required is some kind of reference to the first day in any particular month and choosing the opening value associated with that day. So in January the first date was the 4th January, so the value that needs to be chosen for the opening value of the month would be 3764.61. The last day of January was the 29th so the closing value for the month would need to be 3714.24.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't write any more apparently there is a character limit for a comment. Great!!

Comment: And the day for the open and close changes each month. In February the first day is the 1st not the 4th as in January, That is the issue that I am stuck with, how to find the first day in the month and choose the associated open and find the last day in the month and choose the associated close. Thanks.